# how to do python pip configuration using vs code

Tags: python, pip

I am unable to use pip command either in vs code or cmd although I have installed pip successfully.
It simply shows `unrecognisable command pip`

Comment: try restarting your computer, or check your PATH variable

Comment: did u use customized installation for installing pip

Comment: no , i simply installed python 3.9 and also on vs code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just search for `pywin32` on internet and install it ,mean run it as it is required for pip to run on windows .